# Is it possible to start an activity below the one already on top of the stack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have an Activity A, I want to start Activity B to load its data from my server and when all the data is retrieved, I want to finish Activity A so that B becomes on top of my stack and be displayed

I cannot solve this problem, I have no idea how can I achieve this

Comment: What is the use case for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data in Activity A and when it's done loading start Activity B and pass the data between the activities, you can see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity A do like this -

```
    // 1. create an intent pass class name or intnet action name 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class);

    // 2. put X, Y in intent
    intent.putExtra("x",  etX.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("y",  etY.getText().toString());

    // 3. start the activity
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

In your activity B do like this -

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tvSum;
    Button btnSendResult;
    int result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

// 1. get passed intent 
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // 2. get x & y from intent
    int x = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("x"));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("y"));
    result = x + y;

    btnSendResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendResult);
    btnSendResult.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Then outside onCreate in activity B -

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
         returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
         setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
         finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast receiver in Activity A and start listening to the broadcast when we start the Activity B. After loading the data in the Activity B, Send the broadcast. After receiving the broadcast, `finish()` the activity A.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data using [job scheduler](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html) from Activity A, once data has been loading start Activity B and pass the data.